# Comparing output of DDLGEN from two databases

Tags: sybase

I have used the [ddlgen](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility204.htm) tool to export the database schemas from my DEV and UAT servers. Now I am trying to *file diff* the output but the order in which the DDL is generated is different from both servers.

The documentation for the tool does not appear to have an option for sorting the output. Is there one?

Alternatively, is there another tool available for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding sorting you are right, there's no option to do it!

---

If you need to compare schemas, you can extract all tables and all stored procedures one at a time. Then you compare each files individually.

Comment: Thanks aF.I can see the tables, views and procedures listed in `select * from sysobjects` so I think this is achievable. However, if I'm going to write code to loop over every element and extract I might as well not use ddlgen at all, do away with the file comparison idea and just compare the schema directly through JDBC. There must be tools that do that already

Comment: I've already made that one time :P But yes, just google it and you'll find it. I know one (DB Artisan),

Comment: Having said that, I don't know of a way to extracting Stored Procedure code with JDBC so maybe ddlgen is the way to go